# Mono Android CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: c#, xna, xamarin.android, ads, monogame

I am making an Android game using MonoGame and Xamarin's Mono for Android. At certain points during the game I add an inner-active banner ad by adding it to the view as follows:

```
var adLayout = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent);
_iaBanner.SetGravity(GravityFlags.NoGravity);
_view.AddView(_iaBanner, adLayout);
```

This code is executed within the XNA update loop.

All is fine and the ad displays, but when it is tapped at any time, it raises the following exception:

**CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

I do not control at all when input handling for this ad happens. All I can and do control is when to add/remove from the Activity's view.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: How is the _view field created?

Comment: Inside the activity's OnCreate Method --> Game1.Activity = this;
            var g = new Game1();

            View = new RelativeLayout(this);
            View.AddView(g.Window);

            SetContentView(View);
            
            g.Run();

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap that call with RunOnUiThread(() => {...Your Code Here...});

Comment: I did, no difference. The exception is not raised at that call, its only after the actual displaying ad is tapped.

Comment: I think the problem is that the *creation* of the view is not on the UI thread. Try the same thing with the code in the OnCreate method maybe?